# What does this $\infty$-like symbol mean?

Tags: probability-distributions

What does this symbol (the $\infty$-like symbol but without the right arc) mean? (Marked by red arrow below)

What does it say about the prior distribution?

[image]

Comment: [Proportional to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Direct_proportionality)

Comment: Also, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is often a good place to start with identifying unknown symbols as the name is usually fairly self-explanatory

Comment: @JMoravitz not entirely, there is still that part "What does it mean in this context -  about the prior"?

Answer (score 1):

It is often used for [proportional to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)).

So, $y\propto x$ means that there is a constant $K$ such that $y=Kx$.

In $\LaTeX$ you can produce it with the macro `\propto`.

Comment: thanks, so, what does it mean about the prior distribution?

Answer (score 1):

"Proportional to"

$p(\sigma_{g_d}^2)  \propto 1/\sigma_{g_d}^2$ means: there is a constant $C$ so that
$p(\sigma_{g_d}^2)  = C/\sigma_{g_d}^2$.

Comment: thanks, so, what does it mean about the prior distribution?

Answer (score 0):

`\propto` or `\varpropto` produce $\propto$ and $\varpropto$ respectively can often mean that [the left value is proportional to the right value](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/symbol/?id=194)